# UITabBarItem TItles Jump on Start

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, uitabbaritem

I'm customizing the font in the tab bar of my app with the following code:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
    @{UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.55 alpha:1],
      UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]}
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This is working great except for the fact that upon startup, I can see the text for the tab bar items start above and to the left of their proper positions. Then, after a frame or two, the text jumps into place. This is by no means a deal breaker but the jumping text makes everything feel sloppy.

Has anyone seen this? Is there a workaround? I'm seeing this regardless of screen size/resolution.

Comment: Maybe the issue is you are changing font. Try to not change the font. Also try setting for all states UIControlState. You had only set for UIControlStateNormal

Comment: Yes, the font is definitely causing this but unfortunately, I need to be able to change the font so that it matches the font style of the app.

Comment: @RahulVyas I've tried setting the custom font for all control states, the problem is still there.

Comment: Can you send me demo code?